# How to accommodate fig.show() using matplotlib.pyplot python with pycharm?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pycharm

Here is a basic code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# prepare data
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
y1 = np.cos(x)

# render the figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y1, label="y1", ls="-", color="black")
ax.legend()
ax.set_xlabel("x, x units")
fig.show()
```

The figure appeared for like a second and then it disappears:

[image]

Initial question:
The plot appeared briefly (1 sec) and then disappears because my pycharm isn't consistently running.

Update:
So @9769953 figured that I can use plt.show() instead which is working. But the new question is if I insist using fig.show(), how can I change my pycharm settings to accommodate this?

The reason why fig.show() doesnt work.

[image]

FYI: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.show

Comment: Try `fig.show(block=True)`, and if that throws an error, try `plt.show(block=True)`. Or perhaps even just `plt.show()` instead of `fig.show()`.

Comment: See also https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.show . `plt.show()` seems to be the option to use here, not `fig.show()`.

Comment: @9769953 yeah thanks plt.show() works, But why doesnt fig.show(). I am just using the method my lecturer is using. She used fig.show() and it worked for her and everyone else?

Comment: Is she using PyCharm?

Comment: @9769953 no she is using python IDE. Also pycharm usually recommends/remind me the methods. It doesn't when I am using ax

Comment: Then you either should use that IDE (I don't know what Python IDE is; possible IDLE?), find a setting in PyCharm to change the behaviour, use this method, or ask your instructor.

Comment: @9769953 Thanks okay yeah. she is using the python shell. I will re-question.